# how to write all content from array to file php?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

**I have this PHP page :**

[image]

*For some reason I can't paste it here properly*

I am able to write to file only in the last row, not all rows. As seen above I have tested using echo if I am displaying all content. I do, but for some reason can't write all of it to file.

Comment: You forgot to include your code in the question

Comment: included it as a screenshot now

Comment: Are you sure you have write permissions to `/home`?

Comment: yes, but it writes only the last row of the array

Comment: Don't include it as a image, include your code as text here in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

function [`fopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) with `w+` mode overrides the file because it places the file pointer at beginning of the file.

You want to use `a` mode instead.

See `mode` description: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Comment: martin , how can i contact via skype or other messaging app, in case of other help needed :)